# Exporting a module and a class with the same name/alias

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I was wondering if you could use the same name for a class and a module and use them both in the same file.
Here's how [SerialPort](https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport) handles it using namespaces:

Declaration

```
declare class SerialPort {}
declare namespace SerialPort {}
export = SerialPort;
```

Usage

```
import SerialPort from 'serialport';
const port: SerialPort //SerialPort type
const delimiter: SerialPort.parsers.Delimiter //SerialPort namespace
```

Comment: Well, it is possible as you already found out. What is your question?

Comment: @GOTO0 Well, a namespace ain't exactly a module.

Comment: Maybe providing an example would make it easier for people here to understand your problem. Even considering that module can mean multiple things.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html